# Return value into a variable in a find request mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

i'm new in the use of mongoDB via mongoose and i'm blocked in the return value of my request.

I have my schema like this :

```
var SchemaSalon = mongoose.Schema({
nB: { type: Number, default: 0 },
available: { type: Boolean, default: true }});
```

My model :

```
var ModelSalon = mongoose.model("salon", SchemaSalon);
```

Then my request :

```
ModelSalon.find({},'nB').where({available:true}).exec(function test(err,docs){
    if(err) {console.log(err);}
    else{
        console.log(docs); // I SEE ALL MY INFOS IT'S OK !
        console.log(docs.nB); => HERE I WANT TO SHOW ONLY THE VARIABLE "nB"
}
```

I always get the error "undefined".

I'm pretty sure it's simple but i don't find the problem.

I also test : `console.log('%d', docs.nB);`

in case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get `undefined` because you are trying to get a property that does not exist on `docs` which happens to be an array.

Comment: But in this case, how to pass the property into docs ?
There's a callback function specific to this request ?

Comment: `docs` is an array of Mongoose Documents if you checked properly in `console.log(docs);` and you get `undefined` because an array is not an object. You can either use the array index to get a document and then get the field you want, like `console.log(docs[0].nB);` if you want the value of the first document, or change your query to use `findOne()` to get a single document from the query where `console.log(docs.nB);` works IF there is a match.

Comment: Ahhhh ! OMG i'm dumb !  It's only now that i understand ! I'm fixed to make docs an object damn !
Thanks !